# Assigning classes to a slide within a basic css slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have a really simple (makes a change) slider that is done with css only.  There are labels for the nav buttons and they are unique for each slide.  **Question is , How can I add/remove classes to certain items within the slide ONLY WHEN the slide is navigated to.**

As with sliders they tend to load everything when the slider loads and I want to add cool animations to the bits on the slides so makes it pointless if everything loads at slide one.

[jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/013481b9/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/013481b9/3/)

I have provided some jsfiddle mock up of the slider and the classes animated and fade which are the ones in this instance i want to add and remove on the specific slide loading .. I will then assign them to different bits on the slide...

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}


.fadeInUpBig {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
  animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);


}
```

Comment: in JS/jQuery, on animation complete, get the opacity of the slide and add a class when it's 1?

Comment: interesting idea.... so you are referring specifically to the class "slideM"in which case this might be a tough one as they are all labelled the same classname .. all slides are called slideM ,

Comment: I want to add classes to all elements on each slide potentially... atm they are only images but they will be multiple divs shortly

Comment: You mean to say add classes to all elements within the active slide, in your case `<li class="slide-container">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS allows you to create animations with transitions and keyframes that once were only possible with JavaScript or Flash. Unfortunately, with CSS there’s no way to perform a callback when an animation is complete. With JavaScript, it’s possible to detect the end of a CSS transition or animation and then trigger a function.

Using JavaScript, we can detect the transitionend event; however for cross-browser, support we need to include the other browsers’ prefixes.

```
$(function() {
    //Store a ref to slides
    var $slides = $(".slides");

    //Bind event to the contianed that gets animated
    $(".slide-container")
    .on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd", function(e){

        // Remove classes from all the elements within the active container that starts with the class 'add-anim'
        $slides.find(".slide-container [class^='add-anim']").removeClass("animated bounceInLeft bounceInUp");

        //Add appropriate classes to the matched elements within the active container
        var $radio = $slides.find(":radio[name='radio-btn']:checked");
        $radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-up").addClass("animated bounceInUp");
        $radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-left").addClass("animated bounceInLeft");
    });
});
```

Here is your [entire code](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/013481b9/17/) with HTML+JS+CSS.

**Note:** The above solution works, but the problem is, depending on the browser, it can fire twice (i.e. Chrome supports both webkitTransitionEnd and transitionend). There are ways to overcome this though, by detecting the supported event property. Take a [look at this demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLWrMy) for more details.

Hope that helps.